# Problem Restoring NuGet Packages in GitHub ASP.NET Core repository

Tags: asp.net-core, github, nuget, roslyn, myget

After performing the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore.git
git checkout v3.0.0-preview8.19405.7
```

and navigating to `src\Mvc`:

```
dotnet restore
```

I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/roslyn/api/v3/index.json. [D:\aspnetcore\src\Mvc\Mvc.sln]
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [D:\aspnetcore\src\Mvc\Mvc.sln]
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. [D:\aspnetcore\src\Mvc\Mvc.sln]

Comment: Could you expand your project reference and share the screenshots if anything shows an error or warning there?

Comment: This is not my project

Comment: It is aspnetcore repository in github you can access it via link https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore then select tag v3.0.0-preview8.19405.7

Comment: You could try rebuilding your project and hope it would resolve if still the problem persists then check which dll exactly caused or throwing the error.